# SQL Check for duplicated userid within EACH TABLE

Tags: sql

I am trying to form a sql statement which checks for duplicated userids **WITHIN *TABLE1* and *TABLE2*** (Duplicated userids found by joining *Table1* and *Table2* together should not be recorded.)

Below are my table information and the current checks that I have implemented:

*Table1*: **UserID**, **Username**.

*Table2*: **UserID**, **Status**.

*Table3*: **UserID**, **Username**, **Issue**

Currently I only have 3 SELECT statement which fulfills the above 3 checks and INSERT the result into Table3:

```
 1.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.1'
        FROM table1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t1.userid not null and t2.userid is null
2.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.2'
        FROM table1 t1
        inner JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status = 'DELETE'

3.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t2.userid,'check no.3'
        FROM table2 t2
        right outer JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status <> 'DELETE' and t1.userid is null
```

Now, I want a 4th sql query which checks for duplicated **UserID** in both *Table1* and *Table2* within themself, not by comparing 2 tables together, but each tables individually.

If any duplicate is found, insert the record into *Table3* with

**ISSUE= 'Duplicated User ID found in *Table1*'**, and

**ISSUE= 'Duplicated User ID found in *Table2*'**

Thank you guys.

Comment: It sounds like your 4th query should be very much like the second, just without the "where" clause - doesn't that work for you?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to find duplicate user IDs in a single table, e.g. that there are two UserID's of value 1 in Table1? Those queries are possible, but that kind of constraint is better solved with a primary key/unique index.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, I am finding a sql query which inserts the record in only when a duplicated record is found within each *Table1* and *Table2* itself. Thus, the issues will be 'Duplicated record found in Table1', and 'Duplicated record found in Table2'. Thank you

Comment: Hi SWeko Because I am importing 2 excel sheets into the databases, if I set primary key to the database, the records imported will not be accurate IF there are any duplicates. Thus I need to do a check on both tables if any duplicated userids are found in EACH table itself.

Comment: What's wrong with a `GROUP BY UserID` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` for duplicate detection? It works fine on a table by itself, and if you want to compare within two tables then `UNION ALL` them first.

Comment: @todda.speot.is do you minding giving me the code using GROUP BY UserID and HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ?

Comment: Observe the results of `SELECT UserID FROM Table1 GROUP BY UserID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and `SELECT UserID FROM ( SELECT UserID FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT UserID FROM Table2 ) AS tmpUnion GROUP BY UserID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. It may be useful to you.

Comment: INSERT INTO Table3(UserID, Username, Issue) SELECT t1.UserID, t1.Name, 'Duplicated userid found in Table1' FROM Table1 t1 GROUP BY t1.UserID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1. Do I have any errors in my statement because I couldn't run it.

Comment: @RUiHAO you should post a case (with tables views and the result you want or you wouldn't want) cause your question is a bit cloudy.

Comment: @Oddant I would want the result to display the userid found with duplicates, along with the issue, just these 2 results for now. I received the error "Column 'Table1.Name' is invalid in the select statement list because it is not contained in either an aggregate functions or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: what do you mean duplicate ? duplicates in the same table or duplicate from one table to the other ? ( cause if it's the latter I don't really see how you can have two similar rows regarding their respective attribute : one is `status` the other is `username` )

Comment: Duplicates within the same table.

Comment: @RUiHAO - You changed my SQL, I `SELECT UserID`, not `SELECT UserID, Name`. My example is just an example to show you how to detect duplicate values in general, not give you your particular output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question the answer should be:

```
insert into table3(userid,issue) 
select t2.userid, 'dup user id'from table1 t1 join table2 t2
where t1.userid = t2.userid
```

However I'm not sure if you want to archieve something else.

Comment: Sorry if I did not made my question clear enough. I am finding a sql query which inserts the record in only when a duplicated record is found within each Table1 and Table2 itself. Thus, the issues will be 'Duplicated record found in Table1', and 'Duplicated record found in Table2'.

Comment: Do you have primary key? What DB are you using?

Comment: SQL Server. I cannot set a primary key as these *Table1* and *Table2* are suppose to contain external excel data which I will be checking for any duplicate userids within each table. If I set a primary key, it is possible that I might receive an error when I import the excel data into my database?

Comment: meanwhile todda.speat.is posted a comment that would work as well.  INSERT INTO table3(userid,issue) SELECT t1.userid, 'dup user table1' FROM table1 t1 GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: If you had a pk you could do a self join, however the having count is probably more elegant.